# Datetime issue while extracting data from Sybase using Perl

Tags: linux, perl, sybase

We have a Perl script that used to run on Solaris which extracts data from Sybase and stores
in flat files. The script used to work fine.

However, recently, there has been an upgrade of Perl version and the underlying OS has been changed to Linux. But, after the upgrade we found that while extracting the same data from Sybase through the same Perl script, all `datetime` type columns with milliseconds precision were being incremented by `1` millisecond.

For e.g. -

- Source Column value in Sybase : `2012-03-15 10:14:04.235`
- Extract Before Upgrade: `2012-03-15 10:14:04.235` (exactly same)
- Extract After  Upgrade: `2012-03-15 10:14:04.236` (1 millisecond additional)

As could be seen from above, there is a difference of `1` `millisecond` (`.235` **->** `.236`)

Software Versions **Pre**-Upgrade:

```
Perl:           5.008004 (sun4-solaris-64int)
OS  :           Solaris  (2.10)
DBI :           1.58
DBD :: Sybase : 1.08
```

Software Versions **Post**-Upgrade:

```
Perl:           5.016003 (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
OS  :           Linux    (2.6.32-754.12.1.e16.x86_64)
DBI :           1.643
DBD :: Sybase : 1.15
```

Can someone please help me identify the root cause of this difference of 1 millisecond and help me alleviate the issue? Is this in anyway a known issue, or are we missing something?

Comment: Is it possible that while it shows up as .235, it's really .2356 truncated to .235, and .236 is the same value rounded instead of truncated?

Comment: *However, recently, there has been an upgrade of Perl version* To Perl 5.16.3. I really don't understand why you would upgrade to a ten-year-old version of Perl.

Comment: Is it always one millisecond greater? Can we see the code?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't Sybase rounding up to the nearest 1/300 millisecond?

Comment: @ikegami thanks for our reply. Well, i think that the possibility of the value being truncated is low because the column is defined as `datetime` type in Sybase. If it was `decimal` type I believe it could have been possible. However, that's my opinion only. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks for your reply. Are you referring to the PERL code that is extracting the data from Sybase ? Well, that code just does some string manipulations and generates the extract `SQL` `select` query on the fly, and then fires that query to Sybase.  It doesn't add any type-castng or such things. Just plain simple `select` statement like - `select cust_id, sale_date from cust where cust_id = '1154G';` It could be possible that the Sybase driver is causing this issue.

Comment: @marie20: Can you edit your question to add your Perl code?